# How would I make my browser extention rederect certen urls

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am working on a browser extension. I would like to add a joke where any nsfw/inappropriate websites would automatically redirect to this link https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/040/630/Metal_Gear_Rising_-_Jetstream_Sam_DLC_S_Rank_-_Revengeance_Difficulty_1-58_screenshot.png (jetstream sam (from metal gear revengince) nodding. Any way to do this?

Comment: I am no browser extension expert, but I guess you would need a list of nsfw sites. Then check with `window.location.href.includes("nfsw-site")` if the user is currently on said site. If so, redirect with `window.location.href = jetstream-sam-image`.

Comment: that may work. I will try to add it